# multiple JButton Action EventListener not following if statements

Tags: java, if-statement

I am having an issue with the following code. the ActionEventListener does not seem to be following my "if" statements properly. When compiled, regardless of which button I press, it implements the following if statement as if the "Purchase" button was pressed. Before I put a purchase operation in, it was quitting. If I press the "Help" button, it comes up with the appropriate message first, but once OK is hit, then the program acts as if the program then automatically hit the "Purchase" button, then immediately the quit button

I did try this with If else statements, however I was then getting the error message "'else' without 'if'"

any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 public class Gui extends JFrame {

    private JButton purchaseSeats, selectSeats, helpInfo, viewReciept, quit;

    public Gui(){
        super ("Cinema Seat Booking and Selection Program");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());


        purchaseSeats = new JButton("Purchase Seats");
        selectSeats = new JButton("Select Seats");
        helpInfo = new JButton("Help");
        viewReciept = new JButton("Reciept");
        quit = new JButton("Quit");

        //add buttons to GUI
        add(purchaseSeats);
        add(selectSeats);
        add(helpInfo);
        add(viewReciept);
        add(quit);

        //tool tips
        purchaseSeats.setToolTipText("Purchase randomly allocated seating");
        selectSeats.setToolTipText("Select specific seats for purchasing");
        helpInfo.setToolTipText("Instruction on how to use the Cinema Seat "
                + "Booking and Selection Program");
        viewReciept.setToolTipText("View the reciept for all the seats you have"
                + " purchased");
        quit.setToolTipText("Exit the program");

        //action listeners
        purchaseSeats.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        selectSeats.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        helpInfo.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        viewReciept.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        quit.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
        {
            if(event.getSource()==helpInfo){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Help Menu"
                }
            if (event.getSource()==purchaseSeats);
            {
                //insert instructions for purchasing seats

            }

            if (event.getSource()==selectSeats);
            {
                //insert instructions for purchasing seats
            }

            if (event.getSource()==viewReciept);
            {
                //insert instructions for purchasing seats
            }

            if  (event.getSource()==quit);
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object`'s `equals()` method, instead of `==` operator, which compares only object references.

Comment: Thanks for that, I tried that, but it did not help unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I do it in this way:

Adding ActionListener to JButton:

```
jbutton.addActionListener(this);
```

Setting ActionCommand to JButton:

```
jbutton.setActionCommand("jbutton1");
```

actionperformed method:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getActionCommand.equals("jbutton1"){
       .....
    }
}
```

Comment: Same issue is still occuring. Thanks for your help this is what it looks like now (I may have missunderstood)